# word: DoCmd.SetWarnings FALSE

Tags: vba

i am getting OBJECT REQUIRED on error on this

anyone know whats going on ?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
Module1.TransferShipper
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide more context and a full code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DoCmd` does not exist in the Word object model.

If you provide more context we might find other options for what you are trying to do.

Comment: i will mark this correct thank sso much